# Strange error on Kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka

In our production Kafka broker I found this strange error in server.log. Due to this message sending in one of the topic was impacted. Producer was getting error "Partition count is 0: should refresh metadata". Kafka version 0.10.0.1. Open JDK Java 1.8

Can anyone help me out as to what could this mean?

```
[2018-01-10 17:23:51,411] ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.IDN
        at javax.net.ssl.SNIHostName.<init>(SNIHostName.java:175)
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerNameExtension.<init>(ServerNameExtension.java:137)
        at sun.security.ssl.HelloExtensions.<init>(HelloExtensions.java:78)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ClientHello.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:250)
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:217)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:336)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:414)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:270)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:62)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:338)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:291)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:476)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:416)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing this class "java.net.IDN". I'm not sure why. This appears to be a base JDK class. I'd start by looking to make sure your jdk is complete and not missing pieces?

Comment: @dawsaw how to ensure if this class is present in JDK? Could you please help out?

Comment: Try using a combination of find and jar -tf to look for the missing class and if it doesn't exist, it's worth reinstalling the jdk.